# CoreData and CloudKit sharing, Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, uikit, cloudkit

```
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
    
    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MYNAME")
    let appGroupId: String = "GROUPDID"

    guard let privateStoreDescription = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
        fatalError("Unable to get persistentStoreDescription")
    }
    
    privateStoreDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
    privateStoreDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
    
    guard let containerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(
        forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroupId
    ) else {
        fatalError("Unable to find container URL")
    }
    
    privateStoreDescription.url = containerURL.appendingPathComponent("private.sqlite")
    let sharedStoreURL = containerURL.appendingPathComponent("shared.sqlite")
    
    guard let sharedStoreDescription = privateStoreDescription.copy() as? NSPersistentStoreDescription else {
        fatalError("Copying the private store description returned an unexpected value.")
    }
    
    sharedStoreDescription.url = sharedStoreURL
    
    guard let containerIdentifier = privateStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions?.containerIdentifier else {
        fatalError("Unable to get containerIdentifier")
    }
    let sharedStoreOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: containerIdentifier)
    sharedStoreOptions.databaseScope = .shared
    sharedStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = sharedStoreOptions
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions.append(sharedStoreDescription)
    
    container.loadPersistentStores { loadedStoreDescription, error in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Failed to load persistent stores: \(error)")
        } else if let cloudKitContainerOptions = loadedStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions {
            guard let loadedStoreDescritionURL = loadedStoreDescription.url else { return }
            if cloudKitContainerOptions.databaseScope == .private {
                let privateStore = container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStore(for: loadedStoreDescritionURL)
                self._privatePersistentStore = privateStore
            } else if cloudKitContainerOptions.databaseScope == .shared {
                let sharedStore = container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStore(for: loadedStoreDescritionURL)
                self._sharedPersistentStore = sharedStore
            }
        }
    }
    
    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    
    do {
        try container.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to pin viewContext to the current generation: \(error)")
    }
    
    return container
}()
```

This is my persistent container. And this is my code to share a CoreData object:

```
private func createShare() {
    isLoading = true
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
       stack.persistentContainer.share([currentList], to: nil) { objectIDs, share, container, error in
           print("start sharing")
```

Sometimes (I am talking like 1 out of 50 times) the persistentContainer.share function never enter the completion and if I am lucky to catch this scenario I see thousand of log in the console like:

```
CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitMetadataModelMigrator calculateMigrationStepsWithConnection:error:](465): Skipping migration for 'ANSCKRECORDZONEMETADATA' because it already has a column named 'ZSUPPORTSZONESHARING'
```

or

CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -PFCloudKitImportZoneContext initializeCachesWithManagedObjectContext:andObservedStore:error:: Deleting record with id

And it never print the "start sharing". In some TestFlight this never happen, but there is a friend on TestFlight that is not able to share and I guess it is due to this problem that I am occasionally (very rarely) facing when building with Xcode.

Have you ever faced something like this? Did you find any solution? iCloud kit is already deployed in production, and I am not facing any issue with my TestFlight. Even if he delete and reinstall the app is still facing the infinite loader.